# Issues implementing a UIScrollView and a UIPageControl together

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a UIScrollView that is 320 by 100 (width and height) and UIPageControl with 4 pages. My App has 4 icons at the top in the scroll view but only displays one of the icons with portions of the other icons on the edges (so the user can know that they can scroll). The user can either tap on the pagecontrol to have it change left or right and it correspondingly changes the icons in the scroll view. On the same point, the user can scroll the scroll view and I want it to center on the icon they are scrolling towards and the page control to change. My issue is that whenever I scroll in the IOS simulator, the icons are offset weirdly and display as such regardless of how much I change the parameters I am moving to. It always skips the second icon.

Here is the code for the ScrollViewDidScroll

```
`- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
float roundedValue = floor(_ScrollView.contentOffset.x / 160);//320
NSLog(@"%f",roundedValue);
self.pageControl.currentPage = roundedValue;
[_dataTable reloadData];
}`
```

And here is the code  for my pageAction

```
UIPageControl *pageCon = (UIPageControl *)sender;
int pageMoved = pageCon.currentPage;
CGRect movedTo = CGRectMake((pageMoved*190), 0, 320, 100);//160
[_ScrollView scrollRectToVisible:movedTo animated:YES];
```

All the math works out, im just not sure why its offsetting the images and skipping the second icon.

Comment: Forgot to mention, that if I spread the icons out so that each icon has its own "scroll view" (ie each icon is centered at 320 by 100),it works just fine. It isn't off centered, nor will it skip the second icon